Mixed membership pricing types
Is it (and how) possible to have a mixed set of pricing for a membership that allows both fixed options and a free option like this (it's just a test) where the field text option should also be a membership pricing and not just an extra contribution field? :

this use case is to simplify the membership where most common options are offered but as an alternative, a member could also decide to give a certain custom amount (like 125€) but still with a minimum required amount. I can't find this possibility out of the box.

I don't see how it is possible without customisation. several suggestions here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3876/membership-name-your-own-price-above-minimum-on-contribution-page and an issue was opened here but despite implying it was funded, it remains open, https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17470

thanks Pete, I'll try with some jQuery in a dedicated extension
